# Lowest cost to convert one string to another

Tags: string, algorithm

Suppose we want to convert one string S1 to another string S2 using only 3 types of operations:

```
-Insert(pos,char) (costs 8)
-Delete(pos) (costs 6)
-Replace(pos,char) (costs 8)
```

Find the sequence of steps to convert S1 to S2 such that the cost to convert S1 to S2 is minimum.
Eg. 'calculate' to 'late' - the possible operations are

```
Delete(0)
Delete(1)
Delete(2)
Delete(3)
Delete(4)
```

and the above sequence of operations costs 30.

I am using the following code to do this but its not giving correct results.
The algorithm used is Levenshtein.

```
tuples=[]
ops=[]
s1=''
s2=''
def levenshtein(a,b):
    global s1,s2
    n, m = len(a), len(b)
    if n > m:
        a,b = b,a
        n,m = m,n
    s1,s2=a,b
    current = range(n+1)
    for i in range(0,len(current)):
        current[i]=current[i]*8
    tuples.append(current)
    for i in range(1,m+1):
        previous, current = current, [i*8]+[0]*n
        for j in range(1,n+1):
            add, delete = previous[j]+6, current[j-1]+8
            change = previous[j-1]
            if a[j-1] != b[i-1]:
                change=change+8
            current[j] = min(add, delete, change)
        tuples.append(current)
    return current[n]
print levenshtein('calculate','late')
```

Comment: What do you think? Post your solution and we'll discuss it.

Comment: How can I add code here?

Comment: @user1471283 Click on `edit` and insert the code. Make sure you put four space characters in front of every code line to get the formatting right. And please reduce the code to the relevant minimum.

Comment: Also note that the 5 operations you list will not produce "late" from "calculate", but will produce "aclt". You need to either delete 4,3,2,1,0 or 0,0,0,0,0.

Comment: There are at least two errors in the code: 1) First line in the `i`-loop should calculate the cost as `[i*6]+[0]*n`, i.e. `6` instead of `8` because it reflects deletion. 2) First line in the `j`-loop should start with `delete,add` instead of `add,delete`, because the left element of the tuple is in fact the cost for deletion, the right element is that for insertion.

Comment: These two fixes solve the problem described by the question. However, there is another issue: Since you swap `a` and `b` to ensure `a` is shorter than `b`, using different costs for insertion vs. deletion is kind of strange, because any insertion from a to b becomes a deletion when you go from b to a.

Comment: I think you should simply remove the lines that swap `a` and `b`. It's unnecessary. Or rather, you should always swap them if you want the distance going from `a` to `b` rather than from `b` to `a`.

Comment: This is a part of the problem I am trying to solve, so I didn't add more details.

Comment: @jogojapan I changed cost from 8 to 6 in i loop. And changed the delete,add also. It seems working fine now. Will have to check for more test cases.

Comment: @user1471283 Ok. Keep in mind that as long as you swap `a` and `b` depending on which is longer, you'll get into trouble when dealing with inserts and deletes. With the two changes you've made, you will always calculate the cost from the longer string to the shorter, rather than from `a` to `b`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm

Comment: Then you're not using it right. That's why you should post your solution.

Comment: @user1471283 Have you adjusted the cost function of your implementation? The default is a cost of 1 for all three operations, but your cost is 8, 6, 8, respectively.

Comment: Yes I did adjust the cost function.

Comment: @user1471283 -  I think you can tick the answer as "accepted" now

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this problem using [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). Use a two dimensional array `mem[n1][n2]` where `mem[i][j]` stores the minimum cost to convert the suffix of first string starting from position `i` to the suffix of the second string starting at `j`.

Your approach seems greedy and also I think it will be extremely slow for bigger examples.

Comment: I am using dynamic programming and storing the minimum cost to convert the suffix of first string starting from position i to the suffix of the second string starting at j.

Comment: @user1471283 you will have to add a way more detailed explanation to your algorithm then. I don't seem to quite understand what you are doing it seems.